# How can I fix this Combinations calculating(nCr) program?

Tags: c, combinations, ncr

I have created this simple program using c to calculate combinations. But whenever I enter large value like 20,30,40.. for variable 'n' and for 'r' program output is not true. But this program works fine with small numbers like 5,7,10... How can i fix this problem to find combinations even input big numbers for n and r ?

***Also I wanna use nCr = n-1Cr + n-1Cr-1 rule in this program and I am using C language***

```
#include <stdio.h>

int fact(int i){             

    if(i <= 1){
        return 1;       
    }
    return i * fact(i-1);
} 


int nCr(int n,int r){

    int nCr;

    if(r == 0 || n == r){
        nCr = 1;
    }else{

        nCr = (fact(n-1)/(fact(r) * fact(n-1-r))) + (fact(n-1)/(fact(r-1) * fact(n-r)));

    }
    return nCr;
}

int main(){

    int n,r;

    printf("Enter n : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    printf("Enter r : ");
    scanf("%d",&r);

    printf("nCr value : %d\n",nCr(n,r));
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you so much for your answers.

Comment: Factorial are growing very quickly and for the numbers you are having trouble with it is overflowing the `int` data type.

Comment: `int fact(int i)` is only good up to `fact(12)` --> 479,001,600‬.

Comment: Have a look at the [GNU MultiPrecision Library](https://www.cs.colorado.edu/~srirams/courses/csci2824-spr14/gmpTutorial.html).

Answer (score 0):

> How can i fix this problem to find combinations even input big numbers for n and r ?

- Use a wider integer type.  32-bit `int` good only to `fact(12)`.
- Compute `nCr(int n,int r)` without using `fact()`.  Form the product/quotient in steps.
- Use floating point math and tolerate inexactness.

Let us go for door # 2.  The idea to use `*` and `/` in each step.

Example, with 52 cards there are [2,598,960](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_poker_hands) different power hands.

```
uintmax_t nCr(unsigned n, unsigned r) {
  uintmax_t y = 1;
  if (r <= n) {
    if (n - r + r < r + r) {
      r = n - r;
    }
    for (unsigned i = 1; i <= r; i++) {
      y = y * (n - r + i) / i;
    }
  }
  return y;
}

int main(void) {
  printf("%ju\n", nCr(52, 5));  // 2598960
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For large numbers use `long long int` instead of `int`.
Try this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>

long long int fact(long long int i){             

if(i <= 1){
    return 1;       
}
   return i * fact(i-1);
} 


long long int nCr(long long int n,long long int r){

long long int nCr;

if(r == 0 || n == r){
    nCr = 1;
}else{

    nCr = (fact(n-1)/(fact(r) * fact(n-1-r))) + (fact(n-1)/(fact(r-1) * fact(n-r)));

}
    return nCr;
}

int main(){

    long long int n,r;

    printf("Enter n : ");
    scanf("%lld",&n);
    printf("Enter r : ");
    scanf("%lld",&r);

    printf("nCr value : %lld\n",nCr(n,r));
    return 0;
}
```